# Variable 'dateFormatter' used before being initialized in iOS Swift

Tags: nsdateformatter, swift

I am using NSDateFormatter in my project using Swift language.

I am getting following error:

> Variable 'dateFormatter' used before being initialized

My code:

```
var date : NSDate = (NSDate.date())

var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd:mm:yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change just one line.

You not initialise the `NSDateFormatter`

change below line:

```
var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
```

Complete code:

```
var date : NSDate = (NSDate.date())

var dateFormatter : NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()

dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd:mm:yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz"
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialise, then you won't get error. 
In Swift, initilization completes with ().

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
```

Answer (score 0):

New usage would be:

```
        let date = Date()
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "MM.dd.yy" // or whatever format
        let dateStr = formatter.string(from: date)
```